# Insert an Image to a Ulysses created file

Tags: markdown

Does anybody know how to insert a local image with Ulysses 2.0?  I am using the paid version (not demo).

I often write local markdown files.  I want to include an image.  The image is stored on my local machine.  After I finish, I export my markdown file to a PDF file and email it.

Comment: What have you tried? I've never use Ulysses myself, but I can't imagine it would be any different that any other Markdown editor. Did you include a standard Markdown image link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the documentation](https://sourceforge.net/p/ulyssesframewor/wiki/markdown_syntax/#md_ex_img), you can attach an image like this:

```
 [[img src=attached-image.jpg alt=foobar]]
```

to inline the image, add a `!`.

```
 ![[img src=attached-image.jpg alt=foobar]]
```

Are you sure your image is in the correct directory?

Comment: As you said, the problem was the location of the document.  I was storing my Markdown file in the External Folders options of Ulysses.  This is not supported, today.  Inserting a local image when I used the default doc location worked perfectly.

Comment: @rustyMagnet Thanks, this was the exact problem for me

Answer (score 1):

On the Ulysses menu click on Markup and then on Image. That should open a dialog that lets you drag and drop the image into the dialog which will take care of the rest. In my text the image showed up as a generic IMG icon but when I used Preview I could verify that the image is displayed in the final output.

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you use `![label](url-to-img.png)` syntax?